# Sentry Release tracking on azure

Tags: .net, azure, sentry

I'm trying to track releases in sentry for a .net5 web-api hosted on azure and it is not quite working.

In the appsettings.json I have a sentry section with a release variable defined.

```
"Sentry": {
"Release": "1.0.2"
... }
```

and as part of my build process I add an application setting in azure
[image]

But when an error is logged in prod, sentry is reporting using the value in appsettings and not the override.

[image]

I was expecting the azure set value to override the default config but it does not seem to be case. Am I wrong? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does the below answer help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `Sentry.Release` to `Sentry__Release` in App Settings.

For App Service on Linux or Web App for Containers, if you have nested json key structure in your name like `ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey` you will need to have `ApplicationInsights__InstrumentationKey` as key name. **So notice that any `:` should be replaced by `__` (i.e. double underscore).**

Check out [Azure — Configure Application settings and Connection strings in Azure App Services](https://medium.com/awesome-azure/configure-app-settings-in-azure-app-services-1d50842d167c) for more information.

Comment: To further clarify, this is not related to Sentry or Azure. It's the .NET configuration system: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#environment-variables